# Mapping each sample in a tf.dataset to an id

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

For testing purposes I want to attach an id to every sample in my tf.dataset. Simply counting upwards should be good enough for this.

My dataset is of type FlatMapDataset fwiw.

```
for entry in img_ds:
        print(entry.shape)
```

> (128, 128, 3)
>   (128, 128, 3)
>   (128, 128, 3)
>   (128, 128, 3)
>   ...

What I tried is to have a mapping function that defines a counter inside of it and counts upwards:

```
@staticmethod
    def map_to_id(img):
        try:
            ExperimentalPipeline.map_to_id.id_counter += 1
        except AttributeError:
            ExperimentalPipeline.map_to_id.id_counter = 0
        return img, ExperimentalPipeline.map_to_id.id_counter
```

and then use `Dataset.map` from tf.data to attach an id to each sample:

```
img_ds = img_ds.map(ExperimentalPipeline.map_to_id)
```

Unfortunately this does not work, each sample gets an id of zero:

```
for i, id in img_ds:
        print(f"{i.shape}, {id}")
```

> (128, 128, 3), 0
>   (128, 128, 3), 0
>   (128, 128, 3), 0
>   (128, 128, 3), 0
>   ...

What I also noticed is that my `map_to_id` function is only called once.

```
@staticmethod
def map_to_id(img):
    print("enter map_to_id")
    try:
        ExperimentalPipeline.map_to_id.id_counter += 1
    except AttributeError:
        print("caught exception")
        ExperimentalPipeline.map_to_id.id_counter = np.random.randint(1000)
    return img, ExperimentalPipeline.map_to_id.id_counter
```

> enter map_to_id
>   caught exception
>   (128, 128, 3), 889
>   (128, 128, 3), 889
>   (128, 128, 3), 889
>   (128, 128, 3), 889

I guess I'm not understanding how `Dataset.map` is supposed to work. I though it would take each sample in the dataset that it's being called on and call the supplied function with the sample as an argument.
Can someone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow will run the `map` function once to compile the function into TensorFlow ops. Then those ops, not the original python function, will be applied to every element of the dataset. If you want to run your original python function for each element, you can use [py_function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function) instead.

In this specific case where you want to attach element ids, you can use [Dataset.enumerate](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#enumerate) to achieve your goal:

```
img_ds = img_ds.enumerate()
```

Comment: Ah nice `Dataset.enumerate` looks handy, gonna look into it tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Ok so after reading the tensorflow docs some more I found this:

> Note that irrespective of the context in which map_func is defined
>   (eager vs. graph), tf.data traces the function and executes it as a
>   graph. To use Python code inside of the function you have two options:
>
> 1) Rely on AutoGraph to convert Python code into an equivalent graph
>   computation. The downside of this approach is that AutoGraph can
>   convert some but not all Python code.
>
> 2) Use tf.py_function, which allows you to write arbitrary Python code
>   but will generally result in worse performance than 1)

So the `map_to_id` function is indeed only traced once.
Since option 1) doesn't seem to work I'm just going with option 2). I just need the id for some unit tests, so performance shouldn't be an issue.

Solution looks like this:

```
img_ds = img_ds.map(
    lambda img: tf.py_function(
        func=ExperimentalPipeline.map_to_id, inp=[img], Tout=(tf.float32, tf.int32)
    )
)
```